# Parse XML - JSON file data to add multiple marker on Android Google Map Application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to parse XML or JSON file data to add multiple marker on Android Google Map Application, I don't know how to parse that into map view, Can I get source code for the same ?

Xml File looks like:-

```
 <map>
  <area>
     <longitude>-97.762914</longitude> 
     <latitude>30.282165</latitude> 
     <name>Place Name 1</name> 
     <address>Place Address 1</address> 
  </area>
  <area>
    <longitude>-97.762914</longitude> 
    <latitude>31.282165</latitude> 
    <name>Place Name 3</name> 
    <address>Place Address 3</address> 
  </area>
  <area>
    <longitude>-97.762914</longitude> 
    <latitude>32.282165</latitude> 
    <name>Place Name 3</name> 
    <address>Place Address 3</address> 
  </area>
 </map>
```

Comment: Have you tried googling "android google map tutorial" ?  There seems to be a few tutorials out there.

Comment: what is your problem..........parsing or google map????

Comment: i have tried but getting static tutorials not parsing xml data to google map to show multiple markers or locations, and do you have some links or tutorials for the same....

Answer (score 0):

For xml parsing, follow below two links:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334859/Parsing-XML-in-Android-with-SAX

placing multiple makers on google map, watch this:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/493833/Android/Mobile/Multiple-Markers-Google-Map-Android

http://androidcodeplace.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-multiple-markers-on-android-map.html

Hope, these will helps you..

Comment: Lokesh thanks to help, but buddy right now i am just willing to work on that project in which i am able to get data from xml or json file into mapview only not in listview...help for the same

Comment: that's fine.. First your save your Lat and lang values into listview , then load these values into your map as markers..

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, could you please show some source how can i do this, because friend i just wanna complete my module, due to shortage of time.....place complete code, then i will use that in my manner.